# how to delete record using eloquent in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have done create, edit and update now I am trying to delete record using id but it's throwing exception `MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:`, what I am doing wrong.

Route:

```
Route::delete('authors/{id}/delete', array('as' => 'delete_route', 'uses' => 'authors_controller@delete'));
```

Controller:

```
public function delete($id){
$author = author::find($id);
$author->delete();
return redirect('authors');
}
```

Form:

```
    {!! Form::open($author, ['method'=> 'delete', 'url' => 'authors/' . $author->id . '/delete']) !!}

    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: What does the generated <form> tag look like on your page?

Comment: I was just following the tutorial

Comment: Can you paste the resulting HTML for the open form tag here?